# why my clearInterval doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

Using the node.js,I set a timer to connect the TCP server.when it success ,it will be cleared.However it doesn't work.just like this:

```
var net = require('net');
var connectTransferTick=null;

var client ;
client = new net.Socket();
function clientConnect() {
    client.connect(8009, '127.0.0.1', function () {
        console.log('success，clear timer');
        if(connectTransferTick!=null);
        {
            clearInterval(connectTransferTick);
        }
    });
    client.on('error',function()
    {});
    client.on('close', function () {
        console.log('The server had been closed,Try to connect it again later');
        if(connectTransferTick!=null)
        {
            console.log(clearInterval(connectTransferTick));
        }
        connectTransferTick = setInterval(clientConnect,1000);
    });
}
clientConnect();
```

Run it ,you will find the timer cann't clear.

while,I Just put this code in the function clientConnect(),like this:

```
function clientConnect() {
    client = new net.Socket();
```

The timer could be cleared.I can't explaint it.why ? please help me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Some information/advice on the use of interval identifiers:

**Node.js:**

The return value of `setInterval()` is an object, which contains all of the information about the interval you created. Even after calling `clearInterval()` with the object as an parameter, the object is not set to null. You should check the object's `_repeat` flag to check whether the interval is running or not.

```
var interval_id = setInterval(function() {  }, 10000);

if (interval_id._repeat)
{
    clearInterval(interval_id);
}
```

**Client-side javascript:**

The return value of `setInterval()` is an int, which is the id of the interval you created. When you call `clearInterval()`, it doesn't unset the variable that stores this integer id. You should do this manually after calling `clearInterval()` if you are going to use it as a flag for whether the interval is running or not.

```
var interval_id = setInterval(function() {  }, 10000);

if (interval_id)
{
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    interval_id = null;
}
```

Comment: As the OP have the code on node.js, the return of setInterval is an `Object`, please see [Nodejs#Timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg)

Comment: Thanks for that, @fuyushimoya! I was not aware it was any different from the client-side javascript implementation. After brief testing to verify, I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think because setInterval is called when the Socket connection is closed, but you're attempting to cancel the interval earlier than this, when the Socket is first opened.

Thus, when you call

```
clearInterval(connectTransferTick)
```

at this point `connectTransferTick` is still `null`, because

```
connectTransferTick = setInterval()
```

has not yet happened.

Answer (score 0):

Because when the `close` is met, it will cause the `clientConnect` to be call at least again, and register another `onclose` to client. So every time the close is met, you register more `setInterval` while you can only clear the latest.

So

```
function clientConnect() {
    client = new net.Socket();
```

works because you create a new socket, and it haven't defined the `onclose` handler yet, so it won't execute `setInterval` more than once.

So you should use a flag to prevent register the events many times:

```
var net = require('net');
var connectTransferTick=null;

var client ;
client = new net.Socket();
function clientConnect(isInited) {
    client.connect(8009, '127.0.0.1', function () {
        console.log('success，clear timer');
        if(connectTransferTick!=null);
        {
            clearInterval(connectTransferTick);
        }
    });

    // Prevent events registered many times.
    if (!isInited) {
        client.on('error',function(){});
        client.on('close', function () {
            console.log('The server had been closed,Try to connect it again later');
            if(connectTransferTick!=null)
            {
                console.log(clearInterval(connectTransferTick));
            }
            // Pass a flag to the clientConnect
            connectTransferTick = setInterval(clientConnect,1000, true);
        });    
    }

}
clientConnect();
```

In addition, I think `setTimeout` should be enough to handle this?

```
var net = require('net');

var client ;
client = new net.Socket();
function clientConnect(isInited) {
    client.connect(8009, '127.0.0.1', function () {
        console.log('success，clear timer');
    });

    // Prevent events registered many times.
    if (!isInited) {
        client.on('error',function(){});
        client.on('close', function () {
            console.log('The server had been closed,Try to connect it again later');
            connectTransferTick = setTimeout(clientConnect,1000, true);
        });    
    }

}
clientConnect();
```